# tflearn custom loss function for cosine similarity

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I have an lstm network in tflearn that predicts the next word in a sequence given a context of preceding words. The words are fed into the network as indices of a certain-sized vocabulary, and are output in binary classes, for example:

context: [45, 243, 1, 1906, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]

label:   [0,0,0.......1,0,0,......0,0,0] (length of VOCAB_SIZE)

However, the model learns to predict nearly the same word every time because I'm using the "categorical_crossentropy" objective function in the regression layer.

I'd like to try evaluating the loss based on word embeddings (word2vec), which I have already generated for the dataset. Thus, the model predicting 'hello' where ground truth is 'hi' would have a much lower loss than predicting 'pizza'. The plan is to calculate the cosine between two embedding vectors to obtain the "similarity" between words.

I'm adding this custom loss function to the objectives.py file in the tflearn installation, but have hit a roadblock when trying to convert the predictions into the embedding vectors.

tflearn/objectives.py:

```
vocab = np.loadtxt('/home/vocab.txt',dtype='str')
embedding_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('/home/embedding')

def embedded_similarity(y_pred, y_true):
    global vocab, embedding_model
    with tf.name_scope("Similarity"):
        #convert one-hot format to indices of max values (predictions)
        pred_max = tf.argmax(y_pred,dimension=1)
        true_max = tf.argmax(y_true,dimension=1)

        #convert indices into embedded vectors
        pred_vectors = tf.map_fn(lambda x: embedding_model[vocab[x]], pred_max)
        true_vectors = tf.map_fn(lambda x: embedding_model[vocab[x]], true_max)

        #calc dot product
        dot_products = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(pred_vectors,true_vectors),axis=1)

        #return inverse mean of dot products
        return -1*(tf.reduce_mean(dot_products))
```

The error returned is:

```
ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0 dims for 'Similarity/map/while/strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [], [1], [1], [1].
```

This indicates that I can't use a tensor to index into vocab (a numpy array). However, I can't use eval() to grab the value of the tensor since this isn't run in a session. So I need a way to set up the transformation of a 1-D tensor of indices to a tensor containing the corresponding word vectors, in order to calculate the loss.

Any help with this issue, or another way to evaluate my model, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: also: the error occurs on the line with tf.map_fn, and points to where i index into vocab with x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used tf.gather to resolve this issue. Additionally, I added scaling by the confidence of the algorithm's classification, to fix a bug I ran into where the gradients could not be computed. Below is the code:

code at the header of objectives.py:

```
import numpy as np
import gensim
vocab = np.genfromtxt('/home/vocab.txt',dtype='str')
embedding_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('/home/embedding')
i2v = []
for v in vocab:
i2v.append(embedding_model[v])
```

embedded_similarity(y_pred, y_true):

```
global i2v
with tf.name_scope("Similarity"):

    i2v_tensors = [ tf.cast(tf.constant(iv), tf.float32) for iv in i2v ]
    i2v_tensorarray = tf.pack(i2v_tensors)

    #convert one-hot to indices
    pred_max = tf.cast(tf.argmax(y_pred,dimension=1), tf.int32)
    true_max = tf.cast(tf.argmax(y_true,dimension=1), tf.int32)

    #extract probabilities for scaling later
    pred_iter = tf.concat(tf.constant(1),[y_pred,tf.pack([tf.cast(pred_max,tf.float32)],axis=1)])
    confidence_scaler = 1 / tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.gather(x, tf.cast(tf.gather(x,tf.constant(5002)),tf.int32)), pred_iter, tf.float32)

    #convert indices into vectors (of type tensor)
    pred_vectors = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.gather(i2v_tensorarray, x), pred_max, tf.float32)
    true_vectors = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.gather(i2v_tensorarray, x), true_max, tf.float32)

    #calc dot product
    dot_products = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(pred_vectors,true_vectors),axis=1)

    #divide by magnitudes
    pred_magnitudes = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(pred_vectors,pred_vectors),axis=1))
    true_magnitudes = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(true_vectors,true_vectors),axis=1))

    cosines = dot_products / tf.mul(pred_magnitudes,true_magnitudes)
    loss = -1*tf.cast(cosines, tf.float32) + 2 #min loss is 1, max is 3
    scaled_loss = tf.multiply(loss, confidence_scaler)
    # loss = -1*cosines + 1

    # return inverse sum of dot products
    return tf.reduce_mean(scaled_loss)
```

However, I am encountering a strange bug. When I try to fit the model, the code runs perfectly fine until it lists the number of training and validation samples, as below:

```
---------------------------------
Training samples: 800
Validation samples: 200
```

Then the output simply freezes, but not the whole computer. I am unable to Ctrl-C the code, and have to start another terminal. There doesn't seem to be a significant slowdown in the system either, and I have tried decreasing both the training set sizes and batch sizes to laughably low numbers, with no results.

I'm going to mark this issue as resolved because I answered the main problem I was having, but if anyone has encountered this type of behavior before please comment. Thanks!